# Feature ranking with plot in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Is there any better solution to have ranking for features with plot in sklearn?

I wrote as:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

model = LogisticRegression()
rfe = RFE(model, 3)
fit = rfe.fit(X, Y)

print( fit.n_features_)
print(fit.support_) 
print(fit.ranking_)
```

Output:

```
3
[ True False False False False True True False ]
[ 1 2 3 5 6 1 1 4]
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It would help if you described the problem more clearly. What would a "better" solution mean? What is your current output, and what is your expected output?

Comment: Thanks I meant to draw the ranking as visually. My current output is as numeric. I will edit my question with output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permutation importance from sklearn inspection plots features by their ranking.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.inspection import permutation_importance

X, y = make_classification(random_state=0, n_features=5, n_informative=3)

rf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0).fit(X, y)
result = permutation_importance(rf, X, y, n_repeats=10, random_state=0, n_jobs=-1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sorted_idx = result.importances_mean.argsort()
ax.boxplot(result.importances[sorted_idx].T, vert=False, labels=range(X.shape[1]))
ax.set_title("Permutation Importance of each feature")
ax.set_ylabel("Features")
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]
[permutation-based-feature-importance](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/release_highlights/plot_release_highlights_0_22_0.html#permutation-based-feature-importance)